# Need a Javascript Graphical Province Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a graphic province selector like the one on this page: http://www.getmoreofwhatyoulove.ca/en_CA/. If anyone knows one, preferably in the form of a jQuery plugin, that would be AWESOME. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This site has an image and map that it offers for your use:

http://camping.about.com/library/graphics/xcanadamap.htm

It's not as pretty as the one you linked to, but the code would be quite straight forward.  Include the image and the `<map>` from that site (following that site's instructions).  Remove the `href` from each `<area>` and add a class or custom attribute indicating the name of the province (or some province id, or whatever you need).  Then bind to the click event of each `<area>`:

```
$("map[name=canmap] area").click(function () {
    $("#hiddenProvinceInput").val(this.className);
});
```